# Check if bigdecimal has only 2 digits after precision using @javax.validation.constraints.Digits

Tags: java, annotations, bigdecimal

I have a following class.

```
Class Item {

   private BigDecimal amount;

   ....
}
```

How I can validate *amount* that It should contain only two digits after precision.
i.e

> 2.19 is correct

and

> 2.292 is incorrect

using annotation `@javax.validation.constraints.Digits`
And how to show custom error message for this ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Why? Why not just call `setScale()` with a non-negative value and rely on the [documented behaviour](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Give annotation to `amount` field of `Item` class as follows

```
class Item {

   @Digits(integer = 6, fraction = 2, message = "{javax.validation.constraints.Digits.message}")
   private BigDecimal amount;
}
```

In the above class `integer` and `fraction` are compulsory and message is optional parameter to `@Digit` and there we can configure custom error message.

Now, we create a properties file with name *ValidationMessages.properties* in source directory. It will look like something..

```
javax.validation.constraints.Digits.message = "custom error message will be here"
```

Comment: when i use integer = 14 and fraction = 4 and i try this number 50000000000000.11111 not working the validation, any idea why??

Comment: @Eragonz91 Don't forget to add `@Valid` annotation to your request body object.

Answer (score 7):

Try putting a constraint on `@Digits`:

```
@Digits(integer = 6, fraction = 2)
public String getAmount() {
   return amount;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Just like to know, how can I throw an exception for this?

Comment: What kind of exception do you expect here? What you could do is add @NotNull as a constraint, so that the method does not return null...

Comment: Just want to throw exception with message like more than 2 digit aftre precision not allow to let user know error.Is it possible here?

Comment: @PrashantShilimkar I don't really know how you would do that, you could possibly create your own exception that checks if there are more than two decimals and throw an exception.